# Sinch conference call error

Tags: android, sinch

I'm trying to start a conference call from my android app but it doesn't work, what I tried is:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(CreateGroupCallActivity.this,SinchClientService.class);
            intent1.setAction(SinchClientService.ACTION_GROUP_CALL);
            String id = String.valueOf(uid) + "-" + call_id.getText().toString();
            intent1.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_ID,id);
            startService(intent1);
```

and in my `SinchClientService`:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_GROUP_CALL))
            {
                String id = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ID);
                if(id != null)
                    groupCall(id);
            }

public void groupCall(String id) {
        if (mCallClient != null) {
            Call call = mCallClient.callConference(id);
            CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

            Log.d("call", "entered");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

and here is my `GroupCallService`

```
public class GroupCallServiceInterface extends Binder {
        public String getCallState() {
            return mCall.getState().toString();
        }

        public String getCallerId() {
            return mCall.getRemoteUserId();
        }

        public String getCallerName() {
            if(mFriendName == null)
                return "The call creator isn't a friend with you";

            return mFriendName;
        }

        public void endCall() {
            GroupCallService.this.endCall();
        }

        public void answerCall() {
            GroupCallService.this.answer();
        }

        public void declineCall() {
            GroupCallService.this.decline();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        if(CurrentCall.currentCall == null)
            stopSelf();

        mCall = CurrentCall.currentCall;
        mCall.addCallListener(this);

        mAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(this);

        mFriendName = ChatDatabaseHandler.getInstance(this).getFriendName(mCall.getRemoteUserId());

        /*location = intent.getStringExtra("location");
        longitude = intent.getStringExtra("longitde");
        latitude = intent.getStringExtra("latitude");*/

        mExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        mExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                showNotification();
            }
        });

        if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.INCOMING)
        {
            mAudioPlayer.playRingtone();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupIncomingCallScreen.class);
            /*intent.putExtra("location", location);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);*/
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallScreenActivity.class);
            /*intent.putExtra("location", location);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);*/
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //this.intent = intent;

        if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RESTORE_ACTIVITY))
            {
                if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.INCOMING)
                {

                    /*location = intent.getStringExtra("location");
                    longitude = intent.getStringExtra("longitde");
                    latitude = intent.getStringExtra("latitude");*/

                    if(mCall.getState().toString().equals(CallState.INITIATING.toString()))
                    {
                        Intent activity = new Intent(this, GroupIncomingCallScreen.class);
                        /*activity.putExtra("location", location);
                        activity.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                        activity.putExtra("latitude", latitude);*/
                        activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(activity);
                        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
                    }
                }

                Intent activity = new Intent(this, GroupCallScreenActivity.class);
                /*activity.putExtra("location", location);
                activity.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                activity.putExtra("latitude", latitude);*/
                activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(activity);
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void showNotification(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_RESTORE_ACTIVITY);
        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        String name = ChatDatabaseHandler.getInstance(this).getFriendName(mCall.getRemoteUserId());

        if(name == null)
            builder.setContentTitle("Call is in progress");
        else
            builder.setContentTitle("Call is in progress with " + name);

        builder.setContentText("Tap to to get back to Call Screen");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sexy_green));
        builder.setContentIntent(pendIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);

        startForeground(50, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mServiceInterface;
    }

    private void answer() {
        mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
        mCall.answer();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallScreenActivity.class);
        /*intent.putExtra("location", location);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);*/
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void decline() {

        mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
        mCall.hangup();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY));
    }

    private void endCall() {

        mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
        mCall.hangup();
        stopSelf();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
        CallEndCause cause = call.getDetails().getEndCause();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Call ended, cause: " + cause.toString());

        if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.INCOMING)
        {
            mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
            stopSelf();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY));
        }
        else
        {
            mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
            Utils.Log("Call ended. Reason: " + cause.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHANGE_AUDIO_STREAM);
            intent.putExtra("STREAM_TYPE", AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            endCall();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Call established");

        mCallStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.OUTGOING)
        {
            mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_CALL_STATE);
            intent.putExtra("STATE", call.getState().toString());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHANGE_AUDIO_STREAM);
            intent.putExtra("STREAM_TYPE", AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        else if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.INCOMING)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_CALL_STATE);
            intent.putExtra("STATE", call.getState().toString());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHANGE_AUDIO_STREAM);
            intent.putExtra("STREAM_TYPE", AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Call progressing");

        if(mCall.getDirection() == CallDirection.OUTGOING)
        {
            mAudioPlayer.playProgressTone();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error from the log:

```
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545): Process: com.galsa.example, PID: 28545
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.galsa.example.call.GroupCallService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.Call.addCallListener(com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.CallListener)' on a null object reference
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3661)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:198)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1759)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.Call.addCallListener(com.sinch.android.rtc.calling.CallListener)' on a null object reference
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at com.galsa.example.call.GroupCallService.onCreate(GroupCallService.java:102)
10-25 19:12:11.671: E/AndroidRuntime(28545):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3651)
```

**Note: this method works with app-to-app call and video call.**

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? i am just in the middle of it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not hooked up the call listeners, `call.addCallListener(...)`, see more here:
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/.

And check here https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/ for code. It for person to person calling but its the exact same concept with listeners.