# sinch conference call hung up right after it starts

Tags: android, sinch

I managed to start a conference call cut it closes right after I start it with HUNG_UP cause and I got this in my log:

```
11-03 17:28:08.940: E/sinch-android-rtc(19101): peermediaconnection: virtual void rebrtc::SetSDPObserver::OnFailure(const string&)Failed to set remote answer sdp: Offer and answer descriptions m-lines are not matching. Rejecting answer.
11-03 17:28:08.940: E/sinch-android-rtc(19101): mxp: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Offer and answer descriptions m-lines are not matching. Rejecting answer.
```

can anybody help me solve this please?

**Edit:**

my scenario is when a user clicks the call button I ask him if he wants to start a new call or join an already created one.

I managed to make my code from this question ([Sinch conference call error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350479/sinch-conference-call-error)) work as my `GroupService` class had some bugs.

I start my call like this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(CreateGroupCallActivity.this,SinchClientService.class);
            intent1.setAction(SinchClientService.ACTION_GROUP_CALL);
            String id = String.valueOf(uid) + "-" + call_id.getText().toString();
            intent1.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_ID,id);
            startService(intent1);
```

and in my SinchClientService:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_GROUP_CALL))
            {
                String id = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ID);
                if(id != null)
                    groupCall(id);
            }

public void groupCall(String id) {
        if (mCallClient != null) {
            Call call = mCallClient.callConference(id);
            CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

            Log.d("call", "entered");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

nd here is my `GroupCallService`

```
public class GroupCallScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceConnection {

private SinchClientService.MessageServiceInterface mMessageService;
private GroupCallService.GroupCallServiceInterface mCallService;

private UpdateReceiver mUpdateReceiver;

private ImageButton mEndCallButton;

private TextView mCallDuration;

private TextView mCallState;

private TextView mCallerName;

//private TextView locationview;

private ImageView user_pic;

private long mCallStart;
private Timer mTimer;

private UpdateCallDurationTask mDurationTask;

ImageButton chat;
ImageButton speaker;
ImageButton mic;

boolean speaker_on = false;
boolean mic_on = true;

PowerManager mPowerManager;
WakeLock mProximityWakeLock;
final static int PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK = 32;

com.galsa.example.main.ImageLoader mImageLoader;

/*String location;
String longitude;
String latitude;*/

private class UpdateCallDurationTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        GroupCallScreenActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateCallDuration();
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    setContentView(R.layout.callscreen);

    doBind();

    mCallDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callDuration);
    mCallerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remoteUser);
    mCallState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
    //locationview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    mEndCallButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hangupButton);
    chat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat);
    chat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    speaker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
    mic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mic);
    user_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_pic);

    /*location = getIntent().getStringExtra("location");
    longitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("longitde");
    latitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("latitude");

    locationview.setText(location);*/

    mImageLoader = new com.galsa.example.main.ImageLoader(GroupCallScreenActivity.this, R.dimen.caller_image_height);

    //mCallerName.setText(mCall.getRemoteUserId());

    mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mProximityWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, Utils.TAG);

    /*chat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GroupCallScreenActivity.this, MessagingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_ID, mCallService.getCallerId());
        intent.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_NAME, mCallService.getCallerName());
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

    speaker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(speaker_on)
            {
                mMessageService.speakerOn(speaker_on);

                speaker_on = false;
                speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_off);
            }
            else
            {
                mMessageService.speakerOn(speaker_on);

                speaker_on = true;
                speaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_on);
            }

        }
    });

    mic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mic_on)
            {
                mMessageService.micOn(mic_on);

                mic_on = false;
                mic.setImageResource(R.drawable.mic_off);
            }
            else
            {
                mMessageService.micOn(mic_on);

                mic_on = true;
                mic.setImageResource(R.drawable.mic_on);
            }

        }
    });

    mEndCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallService.endCall();
        }
    });

    mCallStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private void doBind() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SinchClientService.class);
    bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    intent = new Intent(this, GroupCallService.class);
    bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private void doUnbind() {
    unbindService(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mUpdateReceiver = new UpdateReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(GroupCallService.ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY);
    filter.addAction(GroupCallService.ACTION_CHANGE_AUDIO_STREAM);
    filter.addAction(GroupCallService.ACTION_UPDATE_CALL_STATE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mUpdateReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(mProximityWakeLock != null && !mProximityWakeLock.isHeld()){
        mProximityWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mDurationTask = new UpdateCallDurationTask();
    mTimer.schedule(mDurationTask, 0, 500);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(isFinishing() && mProximityWakeLock != null && mProximityWakeLock.isHeld()){
        mProximityWakeLock.release();
    }

    mDurationTask.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(isFinishing() && mProximityWakeLock != null && mProximityWakeLock.isHeld()){
        mProximityWakeLock.release();
    }

    if(mUpdateReceiver != null)
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mUpdateReceiver);
        mUpdateReceiver = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // User should exit activity by ending call, not by going back.
}

private void updateCallDuration() {
    mCallDuration.setText(Utils.formatTimespan(System.currentTimeMillis() - mCallStart));
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
    if(iBinder instanceof GroupCallService.GroupCallServiceInterface)
    {
        mCallService = (GroupCallService.GroupCallServiceInterface) iBinder;

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if(mCallService.getCallerName() != null)
            actionBar.setTitle(mCallService.getCallerName());
        else
            actionBar.setTitle("Group call");

        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.callscreen);

         if(mCallService.getCallerName() != null)
             mCallerName.setText(mCallService.getCallerName());
         else
             mCallerName.setText("Group call");

        mCallState.setText(mCallService.getCallState());

        String pic = ChatDatabaseHandler.getInstance(this).getFriendpic(mCallService.getCallerId());
        mImageLoader.displayImage(UserFunctions.hostImageDownloadURL + pic, user_pic);
    }
    else
        mMessageService = (SinchClientService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;

    mMessageService.enableMic();
    mMessageService.disableSpeaker();
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
    mMessageService = null;
    mCallService = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    if(mUpdateReceiver != null)
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mUpdateReceiver);
        mUpdateReceiver = null;
    }

    doUnbind();

    super.onDestroy();
}

private class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(GroupCallService.ACTION_FINISH_CALL_ACTIVITY.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            finish();
        }
        else if(GroupCallService.ACTION_CHANGE_AUDIO_STREAM.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            setVolumeControlStream(intent.getIntExtra("STREAM_TYPE", AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE));
        }
        else if(GroupCallService.ACTION_UPDATE_CALL_STATE.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            mCallState.setText(intent.getStringExtra("STATE"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

I start the call with the same way whether the user will start a new call or join a created one.

Comment: Are you using the same version SDK on all devices?

Comment: yes, I'm using sinch android SDK 3.7.1

Comment: And you are trying to call a conference? Can you share the code?

Comment: @cjensen I added some code, check it out please.

Comment: upgrade to the latest SDK of video if you require the video beta, or use the voice RTC and you should be alright.